# Check if a file with a pattern is available in the directory using batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line-interface

A file is dropped in a directory when another job finished processing it.
The requirement is to **run a batch script to check whether the file is available for today**. and if available, I need  to execute certain batch script. (Example: File with **Naming pattern ABC-D*.txt should be available with modification date=today**)

What I have figured out till now is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3* Delims=/ " %%I in ('DATE /T') DO set TODAY=%%I-%%J-%%K
xcopy C:\BatchJobs\Odd*.* /L /D:%TODAY%
```

Running this is giving the output:

```
C:\BatchJobs\OddEven.txt
File cannot be copied onto itself
0 File(s)
```

---

`C:\BatchJobs\OddEven.txt`, showing in console is what I need. But I need to store it in some file or in some variable to be able to use this path later in my batch script. Can somebody help me in storing this file path in a variable or a file? Or suggest some other ways to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) which is capable of filtering files by their last modification date, but not regarding the time:

```cmd
forfiles /P "D:\ROOT" /M "ABC-D*.txt" /D +0 /C "cmd /C echo @file"
```

Instead of `echo` you can state your batch script to execute.

Comment: Currently the file name is showing in quote. Any way to remove the quote?

Comment: `forfiles` expands all its path-related variables including surrounding quotes; to remove them, use a `for` loop, like this: `forfiles /P "D:\ROOT" /M "ABC-D*.txt" /D +0 /C "cmd /C for %%I in (@file) do @echo/%%~I"`

Answer (score 2):

This code will identify "ABC-D*.txt" files last written today. Place the code below into a file such as `doit.ps1` (but choose a better name). I did an `attrib` command on the file, but you will want to do something else.

```
$srcdir = 'C:\src\t\empty'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $srcdir -Filter 'ABC-D*.txt' |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Today } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Do something to the $_ file
        & attrib $_
    }
```

Then, you can run it from a cmd shell with:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File doit.ps1
```

Comment: A simpler/shorter way to get todays date at `00:00:00.000` is `[datetime]::Today`

Comment: or (get-date).Date ;)